# Redux dispatch function and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Having such a simple `React` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { INCREMENT, DECREMENT } from '../Misc/actions';

interface Props {
    count: number,
    asd: number
}

class Counter extends React.Component<Props> {
    state = { count: 0 }

    increment = () => {
        this.props.dispatch({ type: "INCREMENT" });
    }

    decrement = () => {
        this.props.dispatch({ type: "DECREMENT" });
    }

    render() {
        ...
        )
    }
}

type ICounterState = {
    count: number
}

function mapStateToProps(state:ICounterState) {
    return {
        count: state.count,
        asd: 78
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Counter);
```

I get an error: `Property 'dispatch' does not exist on type 'Readonly<Props> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'`.

I's definitely a `TypeScript` error but how to solve the problem?

Comment: Your interface `Props` is missing dispatch.

Comment: @HMR Ok, how can i type the dispatch action?

Comment: `import {Dispatch} from 'react-redux'` and then `dispatch:Dispatch` in interface Props.

Answer (score 0):

Add `dispatch` property to `Props` interface. Since the `Dispatch` interface is generic and it accepts generic parameters, so you need to make your `Props` generic interface.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dispatch, Action, AnyAction } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const INCREMENT = 'INCREMENT';
const DECREMENT = 'DECREMENT';

interface Props<A extends Action = AnyAction> {
  count: number;
  asd: number;
  dispatch: Dispatch<A>;
}

class Counter extends React.Component<Props> {
  state = { count: 0 };

  increment = () => {
    this.props.dispatch<{ type: typeof INCREMENT }>({ type: INCREMENT });
  };

  decrement = () => {
    this.props.dispatch({ type: DECREMENT });
  };

  render() {
    return <div>counter</div>;
  }
}

type ICounterState = {
  count: number;
};

function mapStateToProps(state: ICounterState) {
  return {
    count: state.count,
    asd: 78,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Counter);
```

Comment: I would say that the generic on Props is pointless since the component itself is setting the generic value to any.  Either redux or react-redux exports a type AnyAction that I would use as the action type here.  That’s better than just any because AnyAction is always an object with a sting type property.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Thanks for pointing it out. I should use the default generic parameter `AnyAction`